# Differences betwen 2.3 and 4.2.6 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-2

In 2.3, there's

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

I tried to access for example "/resource/edit", it has no problem to find controller resource and action edit.

In 4.2, I use

```
  get ':controller/:action/:id'
```

The "/resource/edit" does not work. I guess it is because there's no :id?

If I change to

```
get ':controller/:action(/:id)'
```

which makes :id optional, then everything works.

So my questions are:

1) is my guess correct? Which is: for 2.3 you don't need to define optional, and it will be optional, but for 4.2 you must define optional to make it optional.

2) For 2.3, once

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

is defined, is it defined for all GET/POST/PATCH/DELETE etc? For 4.2, I must define the following?

```
get ':controller/:action(/:id)'
post ':controller/:action(/:id)'
```

etc one by one?

3. Is there any other big differences you can think of?

Thanks.

Comment: You can find a lot of information here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: But they just don't tell you the difference, or point out what codes are broken. I am doing migration from 2.3 to 4, I need to know exactly what has changed. Now what I can do is just to see what's broken in testing and try to guess whether it's because the rule has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Yes, this is correct.

(2) Use resourceful routing as an alternative to defining, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE on the same route:

```
resources :resource_name
```

this will define `new` (GET), `create` (POST), `edit` (GET), `update` (PUT/PATCH), and `destroy` (DELETE) actions for the model named resource_name. The Rails docs have a much better explanation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions.

(3) There are likely other differences, though it has been a while since I've used Rails 2.x. I'd recommend getting used to the routing schemes for Rails 3+ as they're a bit stricter in how HTTP verbs get defined for your routes.

Comment: thx, this is just what i want to know, the confirmation. It's kinda painful to guess around whether it's because of anything changed or because I did something wrong.